# how to get specific json data from http response

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my application i am getting data from a http request. in my http response i have json array with 500 values. each index of an array has 10 values. i am trying to get specific value for each index in the array and push it inot another arry. what is the best way of doing it.

```
constructor(private test: TestService){
this.test.getdata().subscribe(data => {console.log(data);})
}
```

```
data = [{t1: 20, t2: 30, tt4: 50, t6:60...t10:100},
        {t1: 600, t2: 30, tt4: 50, t6:60...t10:100},
        {t1: 200, t2: 30, tt4: 50, t6:60...t10:100}
]

// my new array should look like this. it should contain only the values of t1 for each index.
arr = [20, 600, 200]
```

Comment: Use `map`: `data.map(({t1})=>t1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need `map` here:

```js
var data = [{t1: 20, t2: 30, tt4: 50, t6:60},
        {t1: 600, t2: 30, tt4: 50, t6:60},
        {t1: 200, t2: 30, tt4: 50, t6:60}];

var result = data.map(({t1})=>t1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var arr = [];
this.data.map((item) => {
      this.arr.push(item.t1);
    });
```